# Compiling android application using Java 8

Tags: android, ant, java-8, android-jack-and-jill

My application is not yet migrated to gradle, we still use Ant build script.
Recently one of our dependent libraries started using Java 8 features.

In order to compile using Java-8 lib, configured ant script to use java 1.8.
with this change, the compilation is successful, but failing in dex phase.

With 20.x build tools I got

> "Bad Class File Magic (cafebabe)" error.

With 24.x build tools I got

> "[dex] PARSE ERROR: unsupported class file version 52.0"

Seems to get rid of the dex error,  i need to use jack toolchain, however as mentioned earlier, I am not using Gradle builds.

Is there any way to use dex with java-8 code? or Jack tools is the only solution?

Comment: Which Java 8 language feaures and Java 8-specific APIs do you use in your library? If, for example, it is only Lambdas / method references it could be done with [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda). If you are also using new Java 8 APIs it's a different story.

Comment: An example is using a static interface definition: public static IInAppBillingService asInterface(IBinder obj)
The latest version of IInAppBillingService.class you upgraded to contains static interface methods, a new feature that is only compatible with Java version 1.8.